# How to save r dm package visualization

Tags: r, dm

What is the best way to save a visualization from the dm package? I am currently using the viewer to save images made with `dm_draw`, but this is producing low resolution images and is not ideal.

Example:

```
dm_nycflights13() %>%
  dm_draw()
```

I've tried adding `png(file_name = "filename.png"` and `dev.off()` to sandwich the dm visualization, but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for this, the result of dm_draw() can be [piped into DiagrammeRsvg::export_svg()](https://github.com/krlmlr/dm/issues/481).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **saveWidget** function from the `htmlwidgets` R package. You can change the *selfcontained* parameter, depending on if you want to save the HTML as a single self-contained file or not.

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = diagr, file = "diagram.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
```